# Cannot load NTFS filesystem, cannot locate UUID

Tags: rhel, ntfs-3g

I want to load my Windows `C:\` in my RHEL 7. My `/etc/fstab` right now:

```
[root@localhost westerngun]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Mon Sep 19 00:25:05 2016
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#

/dev/mapper/rhel-root                           /               ext3     defaults                          1 1
#/dev/sda7
UUID=8ce330c6-6f55-40b7-8f20-09b9981fc1ab       /boot           ext2     defaults                          1 2
#/dev/sda4
UUID=42C7-F715                                  /boot/efi           vfat     umask=0077,shortname=winnt         0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-home                           /home               ext4     defaults                           1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap                           swap                swap     defaults                   0 0
# C:\ in Windows 10. 
#UUID=DE783A197839F13F                           /dev/sda3           ntfs     defaults,windows_names             0 0
```

Note that I have commented the last line. With this line commented, if I run `fdisk -l`, I am getting:

```
[root@localhost westerngun]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       739327    360M  EFI System      EFI system partition
 2       739328      1001471    128M  Microsoft reser Microsoft reserved partition
 3      1001472   1820127231  867.4G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
 4   1820127232   1820639231    250M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 5   1924984832   1926711295    843M  Windows recover Basic data partition
 6   1926711296   1953523711   12.8G  Windows recover Basic data partition
 7   1820639232   1821151231    250M  Microsoft basic 
 8   1821151232   1924984831   49.5G  Linux LVM       

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root: 16.0 GB, 16034824192 bytes, 31318016 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap: 17.4 GB, 17381195776 bytes, 33947648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-home: 19.7 GB, 19742588928 bytes, 38559744 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And when running `sudo blkid`:

```
[root@localhost westerngun]# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="C28C-7B9B" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b1a4ddf9-30be-40e1-a999-537297adb9fd" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="DE783A197839F13F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d48db54e-be85-4159-ab1e-2984d53296fb" 
/dev/sda4: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="42C7-F715" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="d904afce-f412-469f-9d5e-ea702dd759ac" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="WINRE" UUID="74A00E9FA00E6846" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="74c18fc7-f9be-42de-8be7-e115d2f69a3e" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Recovery Image" UUID="02E85FE9E85FD98D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f5129ec8-d418-45da-aed6-c15f079dabae" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="8ce330c6-6f55-40b7-8f20-09b9981fc1ab" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="c02cce33-4891-40ff-b8b9-2f41a024f9ea" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="Ae24dQ-T5jR-gfCF-XrbQ-BsiX-pgMF-FFjPRt" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="c9e4b034-15d6-4e7d-9700-6fb7893c4a0a" 
/dev/mapper/rhel-root: UUID="c4e1c73c-ca07-4f39-85d3-7b7ad9ff17fb" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap: UUID="24e048e2-9c35-44c8-8fec-c8822086d3bc" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/rhel-home: UUID="a84c8d20-9e66-4cda-a316-5ff0569e8525" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="303ae459-d645-4340-a799-0eb7983d6995"
```

And `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`:

```
[root@localhost westerngun]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 02E85FE9E85FD98D -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 24e048e2-9c35-44c8-8fec-c8822086d3bc -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 42C7-F715 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 74A00E9FA00E6846 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:59 8ce330c6-6f55-40b7-8f20-09b9981fc1ab -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:59 a84c8d20-9e66-4cda-a316-5ff0569e8525 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 C28C-7B9B -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 c4e1c73c-ca07-4f39-85d3-7b7ad9ff17fb -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 DE783A197839F13F -> ../../sda3
```

From what we get above, we can know that:

- `/dev/sda3` is the Windows `C:/` partition(telling from the 800+ GB size and the label `Windows`, which I can see in my Windows 10), which is the partition I want to load;
- It has the UUID of `DE783A197839F13F`.
- It can be recognized now **when it's not loaded in `/etc/fstab`**.

But, if I uncomment the line which loads this partition in `/etc/fstab` and do a `sudo mount -a`, all the above changes.

```
[root@localhost westerngun]# vim /etc/fstab
[root@localhost westerngun]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       739327    360M  EFI System      EFI system partition
 2       739328      1001471    128M  Microsoft reser Microsoft reserved partition
 3      1001472   1820127231  867.4G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
 4   1820127232   1820639231    250M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 5   1924984832   1926711295    843M  Windows recover Basic data partition
 6   1926711296   1953523711   12.8G  Windows recover Basic data partition
 7   1820639232   1821151231    250M  Microsoft basic 
 8   1821151232   1924984831   49.5G  Linux LVM       

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root: 16.0 GB, 16034824192 bytes, 31318016 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap: 17.4 GB, 17381195776 bytes, 33947648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-home: 19.7 GB, 19742588928 bytes, 38559744 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[root@localhost westerngun]# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="C28C-7B9B" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b1a4ddf9-30be-40e1-a999-537297adb9fd" 
/dev/sda4: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="42C7-F715" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="d904afce-f412-469f-9d5e-ea702dd759ac" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="WINRE" UUID="74A00E9FA00E6846" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="74c18fc7-f9be-42de-8be7-e115d2f69a3e" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Recovery Image" UUID="02E85FE9E85FD98D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f5129ec8-d418-45da-aed6-c15f079dabae" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="8ce330c6-6f55-40b7-8f20-09b9981fc1ab" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="c02cce33-4891-40ff-b8b9-2f41a024f9ea" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="Ae24dQ-T5jR-gfCF-XrbQ-BsiX-pgMF-FFjPRt" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="c9e4b034-15d6-4e7d-9700-6fb7893c4a0a" 
/dev/mapper/rhel-root: UUID="c4e1c73c-ca07-4f39-85d3-7b7ad9ff17fb" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap: UUID="24e048e2-9c35-44c8-8fec-c8822086d3bc" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/rhel-home: UUID="a84c8d20-9e66-4cda-a316-5ff0569e8525" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="303ae459-d645-4340-a799-0eb7983d6995" 
[root@localhost westerngun]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 02E85FE9E85FD98D -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 24e048e2-9c35-44c8-8fec-c8822086d3bc -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 42C7-F715 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 74A00E9FA00E6846 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:59 8ce330c6-6f55-40b7-8f20-09b9981fc1ab -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:59 a84c8d20-9e66-4cda-a316-5ff0569e8525 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 C28C-7B9B -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 c4e1c73c-ca07-4f39-85d3-7b7ad9ff17fb -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 DE783A197839F13F -> ../../sda3
```

`/dev/sda3` is gone. And in this last line:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  6 00:58 DE783A197839F13F -> ../../sda3
```

the UUID `DE783A197839F13F` is in red. Of course, the `C:\` is not shown.

By the way, Hibernate mode is turned off in Windows 10.

**Another strange thing is that `sda5` and `sda6` are mounted with no problem, even if they are not specified in `/etc/fstab`!** That makes me think if the `C:\` is too big to load.

EDIT:

`stat /dev/sda3` shows me an I/O error:

```
[root@localhost westerngun]# stat /dev/sda3
stat: cannot stat ‘/dev/sda3’: Input/output error
```

And if I do `sudo partprobe`, `/dev/sda3` is still gone. The red part is gone too, because it's recognized as an error mapping and erased.

Anyone can help??

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It makes it hard to read, we can't copy and paste it, the text isn't picked up by Google for searches, it makes the question take longer to load, etc. etc.

Comment: The red color from the `ls` output typically means it's a link to a nonexistent file. What is the output of `stat /dev/sda3`? If it returns no such file or directory you could try running `partprobe` to rescan for partitions.

Comment: Thanks for comment. It's hard to read in text so I post images. I will try run `stat` and come back.

Comment: I have reposted the question in text form and added some important details. See OP and edit.